# Macro to use a name from the clipboard to create a new tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report which is run each month and want to create a master workbook that creates a new tab in it for each month the report is run.

Luckily, the report has the month the report is run, so have created a macro that grabs the date from a hidden sheet and pastes it into a worksheet as a proof of concept.

```
Sub Import_Report()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

master = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C13").Value
report = "xxx.xlsx"
report_filepath = "xxx\xxx\xxx.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=(report_filepath)

    Windows(report).Activate
    Sheets("Info").Visible = True
    Sheets("Info").Activate
    Range("B5").Copy
    Windows(master).Activate
    Sheets("Test").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows(report).Close

End Sub
```

How can I modify it so that it uses the name it pulls and then uses it to create a new tab based on that name?

Comment: In your code example what does `master` get used for? is it written as `xxx` further down?

Comment: Good spot, have changed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a sheet to an object so that you don't need to know its name.

The example below will create a new worksheet and then rename it to "My New Sheet"

```
Sub main()

Dim WB As Workbook

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = WB.Worksheets.Add

WS.Name = "My New Sheet"

End Sub
```

Referencing sheets and workbooks like this takes some of the hassle of making a specific sheet or workbook active before trying to take data from it, you can reference the sheet directly. It works even if the sheet is hidden so your secret sheet need not show itself.

**Update**

I've not tested the following code, but if I read your updated code example this should do the same thing. Just read the question and this doesn't answer it. But if you assign the sheet you are trying to rename to a variable when you create it you can re-name it like you suggest in your comment.

```
Sub Main()

Dim Master As Workbook

Dim Report As Workbook
Dim File As String

Set Master = ThisWorkbook

File = "xxx\xxx\xxx.xlsx"

Set Report = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File)

Report.Worksheets("Info").Range("B5").Copy

Master.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Report.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: But where you have "My New Sheet". How do I make it so it uses the Value of the cell in the other workbook? Also, it adds the sheet at the begining, how can I change it so it adds it at the end?

Comment: if I understand you correctly just put `WS.Name = Sheets("wherever the value is).cells("A1")` ' Changing A1 for where the cell is